# When adding NativeExpressAds in between Listview items ,showing error"FragmentManager is already executing transactions"

Tags: android

Adding NativeExpressAdView in between list view items, it works but when click other tabs in app, its showing error

> FragmentManager is already executing transactions

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.abc, PID: 15237
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1643)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```